# Using useParams() in the top level

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use `useParams()` in my `App` component because I need it in two different child components.

But `useParams()` returns `*: "tenants/rdyTupPulEab6mztoLvnQ/projects/0/workspace"` not actually able to destructure the `tenantId`.

I assume this is because `App` isn't rerendering when the url changes, but I don't want to put two `useParams()` in both children and send the data back up to app. This is the best place for it to go, but not sure how to get `useParams()` to destructure the data correctly.

How can I do this, or what alternatives are there?

MRE:

```
function App() {
   console.log(useParams())

   useEffect(() => {
      (api call that needs the tenantId from useParams())
   })

   return (
      <Routes>
         <Route path="/tenants/:tenantId/workspace" 
         element={<Workspace/>}/>
         <Route path="/tenants/:tenantId/setup" element=. 
        {<Setup/>}/>
      </Routes>
   )
}
```

The console.log returns `{*: 'tenants/rdyTupPulEab6mztoLvnQ/projects/0/workspace'}`.

I need it to return `{*: 'tenants/rdyTupPulEab6mztoLvnQ/projects/0/workspace', tenantId: 'rdyTupPulEab6mztoLvnQ'}`

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include a component code example as a [mcve] so we've context around the `useParams` hook and what params it's possibly returning?

Comment: How are your routes defined? Usually they have placeholders/variables (i.e. `/tenants/:tenantId/projects/:projectId/workspace`) which the `useParams` hook can read out properly.

Comment: A likely issue is you can't `useParams` in the App level because it's hierarchy places it above the router definition

Comment: @SterlingArcher If the `useParams` hook was used outside a router then an invariant exception would be thrown. I don't believe this is the case here.

Comment: @DrewReese I've added an MRE.

Comment: @nbokmans ```useParams()``` in lower levels can grab the dynamic parameters, just not here in the upper level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `App` component can't access the route path params of any of the routes the `Routes` component is managing. The options you have are to use the [`matchPath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-path) utility to find a "match" to extract the `tenentId` parameter value.

Something like:

```js
function App() {
  const match = useMatch("/tenants/:tenantId/*");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (match) {
      const { tenantId } = match.params;
      // ... business logic using tenentId
    }
  }, [match]);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/tenants/:tenantId/workspace" element={<Workspace />} />
      <Route path="/tenants/:tenantId/setup" element={<Setup />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

An alternative is to create an intermediate layout component that ***can*** use the `useParams` hook.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export const TenantIdLayout = () => {
  const { tenantId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tenantId) {
      // ... business logic using tenentId
    }
  }, [tenantId]);

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<TenantIdLayout />}>
        {/* "tenantId" routes */}
        <Route path="/tenants/:tenantId/workspace" element={<Workspace />} />
        <Route path="/tenants/:tenantId/setup" element={<Setup />} />
      </Route>

      {/* non-"tenantId" routes */}
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: great, thank you very much Drew. I couldn't quite get the first solution to work, ```useMatch``` was returning ```null```. But the second one is working. Thanks for clarifying that ```useParams``` needs to happen inside ```Routes```

Comment: @Cjmaret Eh, the first option is probably *adjacent* to what you need, i.e. it's close... I didn't stand up a sandbox to test it though so sorry if it didn't straight up work (*will test this out when I can and amend answer for future readers*). Otherwise, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Just leaving this here, useMatch didn't work because I wasn't include the entire url after the base url, but sadly, it seems ```useMatch``` only matches entire urls, and the beginning section of my url changes, so unless I explicitly wrote out multiple ```useMatch```es for each url, I don't think it's viable